# permision denied django static files

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

Today i've faced some problem in deployment of django project + apache2 mod_wsgi

Let's clear some facts:
1. It's not my first deployment
2. Site is responsing with mod_wsgi
3. "static" folder has 777 arguments including files and folders

My virtualhost looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject.com
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myproject.com
    ServerAlias www.myproject.com   
    DocumentRoot /home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/myproject/index.wsgi

    <Directory /home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject>
        Order deny,allow  
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/static/

    <Directory /home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My index.wsgi looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/open.tm/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/ilyas/open.tm/bin')
sys.path.append('/home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject')
sys.path.append('/home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/static')
sys.path.append('/home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/myproject')

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=("/home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and finaly files section of my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static', '/home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/static/',
    'media', '/home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/media/',
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

the site is working good, I can browse pages, I can access admin backend, I can add records via backend... But STATIC files ore not loadnig "You don't have permission to access /static/image.png on this server."

Django = 1.9.2
Apache = 2.4.7

Comment: What does apache's error log say when you try access one of the static files? Does the apache user have permission to read the file?

Comment: [Wed Mar 02 12:38:55.358349 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 32385] [client 94.102.184.31:28078] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/ilyas/open.tm/bin/myproject/static/img/system/logo-flag.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

This isn't needed in 2.4:

```
Order allow,deny
```

Try removing it?

Comment: Man, I've been thinking about it, but I thought if rule is not working then it's ignored... but in fact, this rule toke 4 hours of my life and some more hairs from my head :-)

Comment: I'm glad that was it! You're not the only one that 2.4 has taken some hours from...